# Reading a Rectifier Diode

Tags: diodes, rectifier, identification

How do you read the numbers on a rectifier diode? It only says "06" (or "90") on it (twice, once horizontally and once vertically). I figure I'm supposed to assume this is a 1N4006, but I'm a bit of a newb and not really sure.

Can someone confirm this is correct?

Here's some pictures:

[image: Rectifier Diode]

[image: Rectifier Diode]

Comment: are you sure it is not an 0606 component(ie. Measurements of the device)?

Comment: I know for sure it's a rectifier. All it says is 06 and then 06 again perpendicular to the first 06.

Comment: As Kortuk said, 0606 is the measurement of the device, as in physical dimensions of the chip. 0606 means the chip is 6 mils wide by 6mils long (0.006in x 0.006in). Is your rectifier through hole or surface mount? 0606 would refer to surface mount.

Comment: Definitely through hole.

Comment: I'll step back and let others take a shot since I am not sure :-)

Comment: can you expand on where you got the device from, any links to a vendors page?

Comment: I got it in an assortment of diodes from eBay.

Comment: Since it is an assortment from eBAY it may not be a mfg pn. It could be some sort of OEM number.

Comment: @Kortuk - Whatever it is IMO it's definitely NOT the size. That's just the one thing you can observe rightaway without markings. There is absolutely no electronic component which is marked solely by its physical dimensions (though dimensions may be part of a type number)

Comment: @Stevenvh, I wrote that before their were pictures and I have not doubt you are correct.

Answer (score 7):

This is difficult because the 1N400x series of diodes is made by a number of different manufacturers all of which seem to have different component marking conventions.

ON-semi have a 3 line set of markings with the full part number as the second line.

Fairchild have a 2 line marking again with the part number in full.

Other manufacturers do not seem to specify their markings.

Edited to add

Now that you have added the picture it does not look like a 1N4006. The normal package for the device is a DO-41 which has a body length of between 0.16 and 0.205 inches.  Your device looks like it is 0.1 inches long.

Comment: Pretty close! I guess you used my breadboard as a reference :) Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: body length of 1.6 inches??

Answer (score 4):

My guess is the first 06 is for the part number (1N4006) and the last 06 is
some sort of date code. If both pairs of digits where in the same orientation
I would assume they were one string and formed a part number.

You should post a picture.

Comment: I've updated question with a picture.

Comment: @manico - Thanks for the pics!  However, you should use the picture upload button in the future, instead of hosting them on your dropbox.  That automatically posts them to our site's permanent imgur account, so we don't loose them if you need to reorganize your dropbox.  Thanks!